# Python: getsize can't find file location from itunes xml

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

1) Export an itunes playlist to an xml file

2) Read the xml file with plistlib

3) Extract the location of a song, e.g. `file://localhost/D:/music/Paul%20Desmond/Bossa%20Antigua/05%20-%20Cura%C3%A7ao%20Doloroso.m4a`

4) Correct `%20 for ' '`, etc. with urllib.unquote and eliminate the file://localhost/

5) try to use `os.path.getsize` on the resulting filename and get an error

6) No problems with pure ascii filenames

```
import os
import urllib

fn = 'D:/music/Paul%20Desmond/Bossa%20Antigua/05%20-%20Cura%C3%A7ao%20Doloroso.m4a'
path = urllib.unquote(fn)
os.path.getsize(path)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uni.py", line 9, in <module>
    print os.path.getsize(path)
  File "C:\program files\python27\lib\genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'D:/music/Pau
l Desmond/Bossa Antigua/05 - Cura\xc3\xa7ao Doloroso.m4a'
```

getsize works fine with `D:\music\Paul Desmond\Bossa Antigua\05 - Curaçao Doloroso.m4a.`

How can I change the filename into one that will work with getsize? It would work if I could change `\xc3\xa7` into ç, so I imagine I'm missing some simple unicode issue.

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames includes "Functions in the os module such as `os.stat()` will also accept Unicode filenames."

I'm using python 2.7.2 under win7. The xml file is utf8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn a UTF-8 encoded pathname into a Unicode pathname, do this:

```
path = path.decode('utf-8')
```

For example:

```
>>> s = "Cura\xc3\xa7ao"
>>> print s.decode('utf-8')
Curaçao
```

Comment: Why does print s.decode('utf-8') work, while open('test.txt', 'w').write(path.decode('utf-8')) fails with UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 45:
 ordinal not in range(128)?

Comment: Because files contain bytes; when you're writing to them you are pushing `str`. If you try to write `unicode` to a file directly (without a `codecs`/`io` encoder), Python tries to encode the `unicode` back to `str` using the default encoding, ASCII, which can't cope with the accent. File**names** on the other hand are natively Unicode (well, under Windows, anyway), so it's fine to use a `unicode` string directly there.

Comment: @foosion: `path.decode('utf-8')` returns a Unicode object.  `write()` expects a string, and so tries to convert the Unicode object back to a string using the default encoding, which in your case is ASCII.  You can't `write()` a Unicode object directly; you need to encode it (or let Python implicitly encode it).  If `test.txt` is expected to contain UTF-8 then you just pass `path` directly to `write()`, because `path` is already UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: What do I do to Curaçao to get back to "Cura\xc3\xa7ao"? print "Cura\xc3\xa7ao".decode('utf8').encode('utf8') gets CuraÃ§ao and print 'Curaçao'.encode('utf8') generates an error

Comment: @foosion: If U is a unicode object, you convert it to UTF-8 like this: `U.encode('utf-8')`.  With a literal unicode string, that would look like `u'Curaçao'.encode('utf8')`.  (You might want to do some reading on the difference between plain strings and unicode objects, to save you guessing.)

Comment: @RichieHindle in idle, u = s.decode('utf-8') followed by print u gets u'Cura\xe7ao' but just u gets Curaçao.  Why the  difference?

Comment: @foosion: There is no difference; they are just different ways of representing the same thing on the screen.  The codepoint `ç` has the hex value `e7` - Idle can display your unicode object using hex notation for non-ASCII codepoints, or can display the actual unicode characters.  The underlying object is the same.

Answer (score 1):

`getsize` expects a Unicode object.  Your string isn't a Unicode object.  It's a normal string encoded as UTF-8.  They are [two vastly different things](http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-objects.htm).

To convert from a UTF-8 encoded string to a UTF string, use

```
utfstring.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Humm I think the original file is an XML file already.